# When page loads display 1st image text - hide all other text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created [this page](http://techavid.com/design/test3.html) and when you load the page you see there are 3 images. The sun image is focused(in color), while the others are greyed out until clicked. That is how it should be for the images.

Also when you load the page you see under each image it's own text(i.e. 1st: Sun, 2nd: Airplane, 3rd: Nano), but on page load I only want 1st:Sun to display and hide all other text until their respective image is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give them a css class that makes them hidden or use jQuery and make them hidden (`.hide()`). On mouseover, change that `.show()`

Comment: or for compatibility, show them all at the onset, and then hide the other elements as soon as the dom is ready:  $(window).ready(function(){ $('.classname:gt(0)').hide(); })